# Fetching data from Firestore - RangeError

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have searched and worked for hours but could not figure it out. I'm trying the retrieve data from Firestore but it gives me a "**RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0**".

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class DisplayMenuScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DisplayMenuScreenState createState() => _DisplayMenuScreenState();
}

class _DisplayMenuScreenState extends State<DisplayMenuScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 130,
            width: 300,
            child: Image.asset("assets/images/NeYesek_banner.png"),
          ),
        ),
        StreamBuilder(
            stream:
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return Text("Loading... Please wait.");
              else {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[Text(snapshot.data.docs[0]['name'])],
                );
              }
            })
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

As far as I understand, it gives an error because when I execute the code, the list is empty. People wrote that I should use ListView.builder's itemCount as an initial value or put 2 seconds of await delay to fetch and fill the list. However, I'm a new Flutter developer that's why I could not able to do it. Any help appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `snapshot.hasData` is true only indicates that the call to the server has completed and that `snapshot.data` can be accessed.

However it is still possible that the [`QuerySnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) didn't load any data from the database, for example because there was no data to load. This seems to be happening in your case, and you need to handle that in your code too:

```
if (!snapshot.hasData)
  return Text("Loading... Please wait.");
else if (!snapshot.data.size == 0)
  return Text("No data found.");
else {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[Text(snapshot.data.docs[0]['name'])],
  );
}
```

Comment: It gives me "NoSuchMethodError: Class "QuerySnapshot" has no instance getter 'exists'. Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot' Tried calling: exists..." I guess the property name is changed

Comment: Oops, yeah... `exists` is on the document I think. I updated to use `size`. Also see https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html

Comment: Hey @KorayBarkin Did you get any further with this?

Comment: Thank you so much sir! This solved me to getting an error screen. The problem was related with fetching the data so I figure it out and solved it. Thank you so much for your help!